# Convergence of Fourier Coefficients of a function implies the function is infinitely differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For some continuous function $f$ with period $2\pi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with fourier series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ne^{inx}$, I had to show the following if and only if statement:

The function $f$ is infinitely differentiable if and only if there exists an $M>0$ such that $|c_n||n|^k\leq M$ for all $n$ and $k$, i.e. the corresponding fourier series converges uniformly (I think.)

I was able to show the forwards argument by inductively finding the fourier coefficients of the $k$th derivative of $f$ as $(-in)^kc_n$ by using integration by parts on the fourier series, which from here was not difficult to show that this is bounded. However I am having trouble showing that the second condition implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

This part of the problem was provided with the hint that the following theorem should be used:
Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$ and such that $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges for some point $x_0$ on $[a,b]$. If $\{f′n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, to a function f, and
$f′(x)=lim_{n→∞}f′_n(x)$.

It appears to me that this theorem is only applicable when we have information about $f'$ or subsequent derivatives of $f$, however we are trying to show that these exist, so I am uncertain how to properly apply this. I would appreciate it if somebody could outline a functioning proof, as well as explain where to apply the above theorem.

Comment: First you need to get the problem straight. What you say you want to prove is false; what's true is that $f$ is infinitely differentiable if and only if for every $k$ there exists $M$ such that $|n^kc_n|\le M$ for every $n$.

Comment: Hint: Say $|c_n|\le  M/n^3$. If you apply the theorem to the $n$th partial sum $s_n$ you see that $f$ is differentiable since the sequence $s_n'$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Is $s_n$ from your hint the sum of absolute values of Fourier coefficients from $|c_{-n}|$ to $|c_n|$? In this case isn't $s'_n$ a sum of constants based on $f(2\pi)$, or am I making some sort of mistake here?

Comment: $s_n$ is extremely standard notation for the $n$th partial sum of the Fourier series...

Comment: Show that the series converges to an infinitely differentiable function. Then show that the series is equal to your original function $f$.